# Stream data to rtmp server from webgl or canvas

Tags: canvas, webgl, video-processing, rtmp, live-streaming

I'm looking for ways to stream data from an webgl or canvas element, being rendered on client browser, to a remote rtmp server - live.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Its not possible without a browser plugin, or screen caption application.

Comment: @szatmary what type of data or packets does rtmp server accepts? Can't we extract raw data from canvas?

Comment: Ramp packets. No it is not raw.

Comment: @szatmary, I'm not really familiar with the server side, but can't we use something like a [WebRTC gateway](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) to then send through rtmp directly from server ? We should now be able to stream the canvas through WebRTC thanks to the `canvas.captureStream()` method.

Comment: @Kaiido Yay Chrome has finally added support for `canvas.captureStream()` as of 51.0

Comment: Reading a bit more, I found that it is definitely possible, but it means reencoding on the fly the VP8 stream to h264 server-side before sending it to the rtmp server. IMM, it's easier to just use webRTC, using Janus for one to multi stream, rather than using rtmp.

Comment: If you manage to get your video to the server, try using something like Unreal Media server - it's pretty cheap for what it is and it's super efficient.  I've had great success with it.  The suite comes with a small forwarder that can pickup registered DirectX media pins and convert the input from those to RTP streams to forward.