# Is it possible to stream a canvas element to a Periscope rtmp url

Tags: html5-canvas, rtmp

I'm trying to stream the content of a canvas element to a rtmp URL. I know I can capture the canvas element by using the captureStream(), but It's unclear to me how to stream that to the Periscope url.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40830341/stream-data-to-rtmp-server-from-webgl-or-canvas which asks the same, but doesn't have an upvoted answer either... What you are after should be doable with a server-side gateway, and without browser plugin.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not stream rtmp from a browser without installing a plugin.

Comment: Any particular plugin you would recommend ? Are there any other ways to convert an canvas element to rtmp

Comment: I recommend against using a plugins.